# How to show the value of Select Field Type in PyroCMS's TableBuilder?

Tags: php, pyrocms

I have a field called `type` and it is a `select field type`. I see the values instead of the keys in `select HTML element` of the form builder but, in the table builder I only see the key as the not the values. It is clear that is how they are derived from the database but it there a setting to switch this? I don't want to hard code this. I read some related pages in the documents but could not find a configuration for this.

```
    protected $fields = [
        'type' => [
            'type' => 'anomaly.field_type.select',
            'config' => [
                'options'       => ['foo' => 'Foo', 'bar' => 'Bar'],
                'mode'          => 'dropdown'
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

Comment: How do you show a key of a selection now?

Comment: @Piterden In the database, entries are recorded as `foo` and `bar`, but in my `select HTML element` they are shown as `Foo` and `Bar` since I define them as key and value pairs in the migrations.

Comment: Try `['foo', 'bar']` options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table column value would look something like this:

`protected $columns = [
    'type', // Shows the KEY value for select field types
    'entry.type.value', // Would show the label value for select field type
];`

Note that you can access presenter methods easily AND retain automatic field operations in columns by prefixing with `entry.`.

Answer (score 1):

The selectFT has

```
/* @var SelectFieldType $fieldType */
$fieldType = $entry->getFieldType('type');

$presenter = (new Decorator())->decorate($fieldType);

dd([
    'key'     => $presenter->key(),
    'value'   => $presenter->value(),
    'options' => $fieldType->getOptions(),
]);
```

Also, you can define columns like so:

```
/**
 * Table's columns
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $columns = [
    'name' => [
        'heading' => 'Name',
        'value'   => '<strong>{entry.name}</strong>',
    ],
    'type' => [
        'heading' => 'Type',
    ],
    'categories' => [
        'heading' => 'Categories',
        'value'   => 'entry.type.categories.pluck("name")|join("<br>")',
    ],
];
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. Which file should I insert this in? In my controller's create function there is only the line `return $form->render();` and its paramater is the `[Model]FormBuilder $form`. Should I pass the information using `compact`? So there won't be any need for the FormBuilder? Second issue: I also want to query some other stuff from the DB for the form, should I give up using the FormBuilder? Sorry for my questions, I am new to these concepts. I just want to learn what is the appropriate way to implement these ideas. @Piterden

Comment: You can create the `[Model]FormSections` class near your form builder and do it inside its `handle()` method, it defines what should be showed in CP. `compact` or not is the only your decision. `[Model]FormFields` defines what should be saved in the DB.